# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: mariadb

I install a laragon on my windows 10 and using the latest mariadb database

```
Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.12-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)
```

but when I try to connect using this command

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I received this error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

What is this error?
I don't know what to do.

Comment: Firstly, Make sure your mysql server has running by `ps -ef | grep mysql`, as you run `MySQL` on Windows, you may check your `task manager`. and then do connect again by `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: Hi Fil, I am facing the same problem, did you solved it?

first I tried to run mariadb by clicking on "mariadb-10.2.6-winx64\bin\mysqld.exe"

Comment: what tool did you user @CR Sardar

Answer (score 2):

When you install MariaDB, by default it creates a database called "mysql".

If you delete that database, that exact error will appears. The solution is either recover that database or reinstall mariadb. I spent one day figuring out why does that error appeared to me.

Conclusion: Don't delete "mysql" database from mariadb.

[image: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)]